# DevExpress - Web Dashboard not visible in iPad with Xamarin.IOS using WKWebView renderer to load it

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, devexpress

I developed an app that uses a WKWebView to load a web content where there are Dashboards(DevExpress) in it. But when load the page, the dashboards does not appears. Running on iPhone device it is ok.

Comment: What exactly doesn’t work. Could you share screenshots of actual and expected behaviours? Also share the code you are using to display these pages, including any custom renderers

Comment: Hi Sammer, thanks to respond. Our dashboards does not display on iPad devices(emulator and real device), but in iPhone it appears ok. I'll see how to send screenshots by here.